# picom color invert

Tags: i3, picom

I am using i3wm.

Running the following script in bash

```bash
if [ "$(pidof picom)" ];
then
    pkill picom
fi
X=$(printf "0x%x\n" $(xdotool getactivewindow))
picom --color-invert-include "id=$X" &
```

results in nothing.
I know how to color-invert a class of windows, say, how to color-invert all google-chrome instances. It is more convenient if I can decide whether I want to color-invert each instance.

**QUESTION**
Given the background information as above, how can I color-invert a single window?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.